# Add up numbers in sub documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have subdocuments that hold calorie numbers for each meal. They are stored as arrays of objects holding food items as seen below:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("58f5fde7eecaaf0317185fd2"),
 "user_id": ObjectId("58d2dd4c8207c28149dbc748"),
 "calories": 2051,
 "date": 20170318,
 "snacks": [
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": 3.9,
    "carbs": 58.3,
    "fat": 28.7
  },
  "servings": 20,
  "calories": 426,
  "name": "6 toffee terror whirls"
 }
],
"dinner": [
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": "4.2",
    "carbs": "5.5",
    "fat": "27.9"
  },
  "servings": 47.5,
  "calories": 580,
  "name": "Summer Recipe Pesto Sweet pepper, Rocket & Mozarella"
  }
],
 "lunch": [
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": 11.3,
    "carbs": 27.3,
    "fat": 8.1
  },
  "servings": 75,
  "calories": 730,
  "name": "Wood fired rostello ham, chestnut mushrooms & mascarpone 12'' pizza"
}
],
"breakfast": [
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": 12.6,
    "carbs": 0.1,
    "fat": "9"
  },
  "servings": "20",
  "calories": 110,
  "name": "15 eggs from caged hends - class A"
},
{
  "nutrients": {
    "protein": "31",
    "carbs": 0.1,
    "fat": "15"
  },
  "servings": "15",
  "calories": 164,
  "name": "Smoked thick cut bacon"
}
]
}
```

What I want to do is to add up the total calories for the day added by a single user, so adding up each food objects calorie amount. I know I need to use the aggregation method with $group and $sum however Im not sure how to use it correctly. Any help would be grateful.

What I need is the total calories for everyday that has been entered.
For example

20170318 : 2018
, 20170230 : 1990

etc etc

This is what I have tried however it is currently not working:

```
        user_food.find({username: req.body.username},{$group:{_id:{date:{$dayOfYear: "$date"}},total:{$sum:'$calories'}}}, function (err, user) {
        //if the user exists
        if (err) {
            console.log("something went wrong: " + err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send(user);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` operator for each meal with `$add`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$match:{user_id:ObjectId("58d2dd4c8207c28149dbc748")}},
    {
      $project: {
        date:1,
        calories: { $add: [ {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$breakfast",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.calories"] }
          }
        }, {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$lunch",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.calories"] }
          }
        },{
          $reduce: {
            input: "$snacks",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.calories"] }
          }
        }, {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$dinner",
            initialValue: 0,
            in: { $add : ["$$value", "$$this.calories"] }
          }
        } ] }
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: This works and gives me the correct details. How would i add to the query to have the results specific for a single user?

Comment: what is your query for a single user ? _id  or user_id? Something like       `{$match:{user_id:ObjectId("58d2dd4c8207c28149dbc748")}}` before `$project` stage.

Comment: Using match changes the response to an empty array. I know the user has entries so im not so sure what the problem is. Sorry for asking so many questions, Im very new to mongodb

Comment: No problem at all. Happy to help. Can you show me your match filter ? Updated answer to include match filter for comparsion

Comment: The session is given the value of the users_id
user_food.aggregate({
            $match: {
                user_id: req.session.user_id
            }
        }, {
            $project: {... your method

Comment: Try `{ $match: { user_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.session.user_id) } }` More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237926/how-to-return-response-using-mongos-aggregate/43238339#43238339

Answer (score 0):

Use $unwind before group by date and sum calories,

```
   db.collection.aggregate([{
      $match: {
          key: value
      }
   }, {
      $unwind: "$snacks"
   }, {
      $group: {
          _id: "$date",
          totalCalories: {
              $sum: "$calories"
          }
      }
   }])
```

Output for day 20170318 will be,

```
{ "_id" : 20170318, "totalCalories" : 2051 }
```

Comment: When i try this I get a response with an empty array

Comment: Check i gave match condition  as key:value , change for your requirement, or remove match segment